# Два 4g модема как средство передачи данных

Tags: сеть, роутер, модемы

философский вопрос, прошу не заминусуйте.
Есть два 4g модема от мегафон старых, по сути дальность передачи каждого модема может доходить до 5 км, так как сигнал же до вышки доходит же,  остается вопрос, почему же нельзя использовать его для передачи данных между двумя модемами?

Интересно кто-то так делал? чтобы 2 ноутбука без интернета на расстоянии нескольких км сообщались между собой 4g модемами? То есть такая локалка пятикилометровая получается )(путь даже хоть в реальности километр, уже круче любого роутера)

Кто-то так пробовал? В сети информацию не нашел.. и как отнесется к такому минсвязи?

Comment: Во  первых протокол не позволит, ибо функционала БС в модеме нет. Во вторых на БС есть антенна и усилители, которые позволяют слабенький сигнал модема выловить. Так что начисто переделать протокол, дополнить модемы антеннами/усилителями, после чего минсвязи сильно обдеться потому что вы частоту сотовых сетей использовать будете

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж вопрос философский... Да, в принципе такое возможно, но есть некоторые технические "но", в основном — необходима базовая станция. LTE БС сделать вполне возможно (https://www.pvsm.ru/linux/14391, например), но в рамках вашего приложения сразу появляются вопросы типа "оно мне надо?", "может, wifi таки рулит?" и "а что скажет товарищ майор?", причём последний вопрос — наиболее трудно решаемый (лицензия сотового оператора потребует от вас вложений на миллионы долларов, а отсутствие таковой — бездеятельные затраты личного времени в количестве до нескольких лет).

Возвращаясь к практической стороне: на Wi-Fi пара хороших (хороших!) наружных направленных антенн с коротким (до 5 метров) и хорошо исполненным антенным кабелем способны творить настоящие чудеса длиной до 12-15 километров даже при использовании стандартной аппаратуры (2.4 GHz, до 100 мВт) при наличии прямой видимости между антеннами.